# Update array in Ecto

Tags: elixir

I have the following model:

```
 schema "users" do
        field :email, :string
        field :subscriptions, {:array, :string}

        timestamps()
    end

    def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
        struct
        |> cast(params, [:email,:subscriptions])
    end
```

I cant figure out how to update the subscriptions-array from my controller. Im looking to simply push a new string to the array:

```
def subscribe(conn, %{"category" => category} ) do
        IO.puts category # Will print "whatever_category"
        user = Repo.get(User, conn.assigns.user.id)
        changeset = User.changeset(user, ?)
        Repo.update(changeset)
```

I've tried the following:

```
changeset = User.changeset(user, %{subscriptions: ["test"]})
```

This adds "test" to the array but will get replaced if I add another value.

Thank you!

Comment: Like this: `User.changeset(user, %{subscriptions: user.subscriptions ++ ["test"]})`?

Comment: Thanks @Dogbert, that did it. If you want to make an answer of it i'll accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you've got the old value already loaded, the easiest way would be to append the value to the old list and pass that to `User.changeset/2`:

```
User.changeset(user, %{subscriptions: user.subscriptions ++ ["test"]})
```

---

Ecto also supports the `push` operation which can push an item to an array without having to load the old value in, using `Repo.update`. This feature is documented [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#update/3). Example:

```
from(u in User, where: u.id == 123) |>
  Repo.update_all(push: [subscriptions: "test"])
```

or

```
from(u in User, where: u.id == 123, update: [push: [subscriptions: "test"]])) |>
  Repo.update_all([])
```

Answer (score 0):

@dogbert's accepted answer works, but you should use `%{subscriptions: ["test" | user.subscriptions]` to add the item to the beginning of the list if you don't absolutely need it to be appended. It's more efficient and more idiomatic elixir.